# how to make checkbox readonly in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want to click a checkbox then the checkbox will be checked if i click again that will not be unchecked and if i take a button and click the button that checkbox can be unchecked

```js
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT>
function readOnlyCheckBox() {
   return false;
}
</SCRIPT>
<BODY>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbx1"
  ` onClick="return readOnlyCheckBox()" CHECKED /> readonly
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbx2"
    CHECKED DISABLED/> disabled
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

this code does not satisfy my answer**strong text**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this by Jquery attr() and removeAttr() functions.

Html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test">
<button class="btn">Uncheck</button>
```

Jquery

```
//for check
$("input").on("click", function() {
  $(this).prop('checked', true).attr("readonly")
});

//for uncheck
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
  $('input').prop('checked', false).removeAttr("readonly")
});
```

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brxa8rrw/1/)

Comment: vote up or tick to my answer  it would be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 functions like

```js
function readOnlyCheckBox(el) {
  return el.checked;
}

function uncheck() {
  document.getElementById('cbx1').checked = false;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cbx1" onClick="return readOnlyCheckBox(this)" CHECKED />readonly

<br/>
<button onclick="uncheck()">Uncheck</button>
```